# Javascript keydown event not working when three keys that form a triangle are pressed

Tags: javascript, keydown

I am currently trying to detect which keys are currently pressed at any given time. Like others have said, I used the `keydown` and `keyup` events and log the `keyCode`s to an object. I also added `console.log` statements in my `keydown` and `keyup` listeners. Currently, everything works well *except* when three keys are pressed simultaneously in a triangular shape (on a QWERTY keyboard: `["T", "G", "Y"]`, `["4", "5", "R"]`, etc.), the keys don't log as expected: either one or two logs, or none of them logs. I wonder if there's a way to get around whatever limitation is causing this?

Comment: FYI, you can't access the pressed key in `keydown`. You should consider `keypress`.

Comment: This maybe a hardware limitation as well. [Check this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this could possibly be `a keyboard ghosting` which an issue caused by hardware limitations (keyboard),

you should try to test your keyboard here https://www.microsoft.com/applied-sciences/projects/anti-ghosting-demo